# Scroll Bar for QLineEdit using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using lower version of PyQt i.e PyQt2. I have to do add auto scrollbar for this text box when it cross certain characters . As i am newbie to this PyQt and version is very old just need some suggestion or help .

```
self.name = qt.QLabel("XXXXXX",self)
self.nBox = qt.QLineedit(self)
.......................
..................
self.nBox.setText(bt)
```

Comment: PyQt2 ??? I have worked with Qt for 5 years and at most I worked with PyQt3 which was obviously deprecated in my beginnings. Why don't you use PyQt5? If PyQt2 existed it must be deprecated for more than 8 years

Comment: Assuming that PyQt2 is compatible with at least PyQt4 or PyQt4 (although I don't think so) you should use QTextEdit, QPlaintTextEdit or QTextBrowser that already have scrollbars built in.

Comment: PyQt3 is also fine but not PyQt4 and PyQt5 cannot use this

Comment: As I pointed out, I used PyQt3 years ago, so I forgot because the API is not compatible with modern Qt. Maybe someone from the old school helps you.

Comment: In Qt2, you have [QTextView](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qtextedit.html), and in Qt3, you have [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qtextedit.html). If these widgets somehow don't do what you want, you will need to explain more clearly what is meant by "auto scrollbar".